# Average variability of small data set

Tags: variance, small-sample, variability

I have data for 300 devices and each device has been tested a different number of times so some devices have 2 data points and some have 8. For example, one device scored 5, 6.5, 6.5, 6, 6, 6 whilst another scored 5.5, 6.5, 8, 5.5.

I want to calculate the average variability in the data but I believe I have too little data for each device to calculate the variance and the range is thrown out by outliers, for instance the score of 8 on the second example above.

Are there any suggested ways to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what estimating variability you *want to* consider the variability of the sample rather then "tackle" the outliers? What makes you consider those cases outliers? If you have some ouyt-of-data knowledge to be considered by the estimator, then you should possibly look at Bayesian estimators.